# Posting Search, getting Data but it only fills one colum

Tags: jquery, laravel

So I've wrote and jquery function :

```
    $('.search').on("click", function () {
        let searchString = $('.search-input').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/search',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                search: searchString
            },
            success:function (response) {
                $('.searchInsert').children().remove();
                for(let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    let searchResult = `
                    <tr class="column">
                    <th scope="row">${response.data[i].category_title}</th>
                          <td>${response.data[i].category_description}</td>
                          <td class="table-overflow-hidden">
                                  <div class="dashboard-table-item"></div>
                          </td>
            
                    </tr>
                    `
                    console.log(searchResult);
                    $('.searchInsert').html(searchResult);
                }
            },
            error: function (errors) {
                console.log(errors)
            }

        })
    })
```

What I do except and I also see it in the Consol. That the table fills the columns and I get the matches. But I only get always 1 result and printed.

Why is it happening? Could someone explain.

Comment: You're overwriting the content of `.searchInsert` in every iteration of the loop. Change `.html(searchResult);` to `append(searchResult);`. I'd also suggest you familiarise yourself with the jQuery docs: https://api.jquery.com

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That acutally wouldn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ending up with the last search result only, each time?

Because when your loop runs, it outputs each iteration to the console (which is why you see all of them), but when it populates the searchResult variable, it doesn't add to it on the next iteration of the loop, it just overwrites it, so at the end of the loop it only holds one iteration - the last one.

Instead of :

```
let searchResult = `
```

how about trying

```
var searchResult = "";
$('.searchInsert').children().remove();
    for(let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        searchResult += [your code here]
    }
```

which will append each iteration of the loop to the searchResult variable.

Comment: Thank you, it worked + it's not .= its +=

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was in a PHP mindset where it's .=, will edit my answer.